# Synonyms for "Low","Medium","High" that sort alphabetically

Tags: synonyms

In database queries, clients often asked to group values into ranges, "Low", "Medium","High" which make sense when read by a human.  But if the computer returns strings, they sort alphabetically not conceptually, e.g. "Low","High","Med" since 'L'<'H'<'M'.

We could prepend numbers, "1-Low", "2-Med","3-High", etc. but wonder if there's a  sequence of short simple English words that also sorts correctly.

Comment: Bottom Middle Top

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Bacon Mackerel Tomato?

Comment: High, higher, highest.

Comment: min, med, max and reverse the sort...

Comment: Great answers.  @JJJ I will make that sandwich tomorrow.

Comment: Bread, mayo, meat.  First, second, third.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same question, and I thought of "low", "inbet", "high" in reverse order.  "inbet" standing for inbetween.

Comment: Is "inbet" a common abbreviation?  Please take a moment to see the [help] and [tour] the site.

Comment: Not sure if it is a common or acceptable abbreviation in general.  But I have found it being used in science plots, and as long as we explain what it is in a figure legend to the audience, it is acceptable in science.

Comment: good idea, "intermediate" is similar and maybe more common